# Creating a generic database context in MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I wrote a MVC 4 app. I have some questions:

```
public class DatabaseContext<TEntity>: DbContext where TEntity: class
{
    ...
    public DbSet<TEntity> entity = {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

1. I want to create a generic database context like this `DatabaseContext` and use it for all my Entities defined in database tables. 
   Please, write an example.
2. I don't now how to initialize generic context in global.asax once and use it every time, in whichever part of the project necessary.
   Please, write some examples.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me to what you're implementing is the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    TEntity GetById(Guid id);
}
```

Prevent letting your repository inherit from `DbContext`, since `DbContext` is an implementation of the [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and a unit of work is not a repository (but rather contains or manages multiple repositories).

What you can do is to let your repository use the `DbContext` internally:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this.context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = this.context.Set<Entity>().Find(id);

        if (entity == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException(
            typeof(TEntity).Name + " with id " + id + " not found);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since I'm a Dependency Injection enthusiast, I think that Dependency Injection is the solution to your problem. And since I'm a developer for [the Simple Injector project](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/), I'll show you how to do this using Simple Injector:

**Step 1:** Install the [Simple Injector MVC Integration Quick Start](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.MVC3) NuGet package into your MVC project (I assume you know how to install NuGet packages).

**Step 2:** Compile your project. You'll get a compiler error in the `SimpleInjectorInitializer` class that the package just added. This is the line where you will have to make your registrations. You can just remove this #error line.

**Step 3:** Add the `SimpleInjector.Extensions` namespace to the top of the `SimpleInjectorInitializer` file:

```
using SimpleInjector.Extensions;
```

**Step 4:** Make the following registrations in the `InitializeContainer` method:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext>(
    () => new DbContext("Your connection string here"));
```

**Step 5:** Add the `IRepository<T>` dependencies to your contollers:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> customerRepository;

    public CustomerController(IRepository<Customer> customerRepository)
    {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    // controller methods here.
}
```

Now your repositories will be automatically be injected into your controllers.

Comment: Go look for a DI framework and ask a new questio when you found one that you like.

Comment: Sorry! My internet only by phone it more expensive and I can't do something else. For example look for it by google. I only can visit this site.

Comment: So I will be very thanks to you if you help me in this. You can write Unit Of Work implementation and how to init context in Global.asax

Comment: I already said that I don't have inernet. It is only by phone. So in NuGet packeges there is'nt Injector and I can't download it. In this case you have some anther way? Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: You can always do this by hand. You can write your own DependencyResolver and create controllers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to make a DatabaseContext with a generic type parameter? You won't be to instantiate it in a single place because each different DatabaseContext is a separate .NET Type.

Unless you're sticking rigidly to a particular pattern, I personally don't see any practical advantage of this approach over a single DatabaseContext with many sets:

```
public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}

...
myDatabaseContext.SomeEntities.GetAll();
myDatabaseContext.OtherEntities.GetAll();

// OR:
myDatabaseContext.Set<SomeEntity>().GetAll();
myDatabaseContext.Set<OtherEntity>().GetAll();
```